# Metadata field using embedded Schema is not populating

Tags: 2013, dxa, dxa-java, metadata

Tridion 2013 DXA Java 1.5

I am trying to pick up in my JSP a Page metadata field that is set to accept multiple values AND uses an embedded Schema.

```
@SemanticEntity(entityName = "CustomPageMetadata", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "m")
public class CustomPageModelImpl extends PageModelImpl implements ViewModel, PageModel {

@SemanticProperty("m:analytics")
protected List<String> analytics;

public List<String> getAnalytics() {
    return this.analytics;
}
}
```

And in the JSP

```
<c:out value ="${pageModel.analytics}"/>
```

This works great for other fields that aren't sending multiple values or using an embedded schema, but it isn't getting populated at all for this field.  If I try changing the variable to a plain String, I get an error that Java is expecting a collection.  That implies that I should be getting something that can be mapped to a collection, but I'm not seeing anything.  (I've also tried `${pageModel.analytics[0]}` and `${pageModel.analytics.get(0)}`